# Migrate SVN to another server

Tags: svn

I want to migrate all the data from the actual SVN to another server.

I read about *svnrdump*, but I'm a little bit confused. Is the dump file that was created after the "dump" operation just with revision history or does it contains the whole SVN? If not, do I have to save all the files from the old SVN to the new one by myself with the same folders structure and then load the dump file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, read the documentation:

- [SVNBook | Migrating Repository Data Elsewhere](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.reposadmin.maint.html#svn.reposadmin.maint.migrateMigrating%20Repository%20Data%20Elsewhere)

> Is the dump file that was created after the "dump" operation just with revision history or does it contains the whole SVN?

Subversion repository dump stream contains revision history only. It does not include repository settings, hook scripts, access rules and your server settings.

When moving the repositories to a new server, you should first deploy and configure that target SVN server. As soon as it is ready, you can proceed with moving the repositories. There are several tools such as [`svnadmin dump` & `svnadmin load`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.reposadmin.maint.html#svn.reposadmin.maint.migrate.svnadmin) or [`svnrdump`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.reposadmin.maint.html#svn.reposadmin.maint.migrate.svnrdump). As the latter can operate remotely on live repositories, it may help you avoid or minimize disruption for the end users.

> If not, do I have to save all the files from the old SVN to the new one by myself with the same folders structure and then load the dump file?

You can save the repository dump stream to a file, but it is only one of possibilities. You can pipe the output of `svnadmin dump` directly into `svnadmin load`. With `svnrdump` you can perform this operation remotely over HTTP(S) or `svn://` protocols.

Comment: @you are welcome! :) As a sidenote, make sure that you run up to date SVN client and admin tools. The current version is SVN 1.9.x.